# thrust inclusive scan completes in debug build but fails in release build

Tags: debugging, release, thrust

I am using a simple thrust::inclusive scan call on a device vector. In the debug build, this executes without error. However, when executed using the the release build an error is encountered.

Also, this seems to only affect thrust::device<> vectors?

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'thrust::system::system_error'   what():  unspecified launch failure

I am using eclipse nsight to perform the debug and release builds.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

int main(void) {

    cout << "hello\n";

    int data[6] = {1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3};

    thrust::inclusive_scan(data, data + 6, data); // in-place scan

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) cout<< data[i] << "\n";

    cout << "inclusive scan on a device vector\n";

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_C_0(6);

    d_C_0[0] = 1;
    d_C_0[1] = 0;
    d_C_0[2] = 2;
    d_C_0[3] = 2;
    d_C_0[4] = 1;
    d_C_0[5] = 3;

    thrust::inclusive_scan(d_C_0.begin(), d_C_0.begin() + 6, d_C_0.begin()); // in-place scan

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) cout<< d_C_0[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it is failing the *debug* case but passing in the *release* case.

For debug build, Nsight EE normally includes the `-G` compiler switch.

Thrust (device code) is [often incompatible](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Debugging) with the `-G` switch.

If you remove the `-G` switch from the compile command, I believe your code will run normally -- it does for me.

If that doesn't solve the issue, please provide the *complete* compile command line that Nsight EE is using for each case (debug and release) as well as which GPU you are running on, and CUDA version (5.0 or 5.5).

Comment: Your guess is exactly correct. Thank you. CUDA 5.5 running on GeForce 8800 GTX and Linux SUSE 64 bit.